# How can I search and install Windows Updates through the command-line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, updates, cmd.exe

I need to automate the task of search and install Windows 7 and 8 updates through the command line(it could be over cmd, vbs or powershell), there is some way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box it can be a PITA to do (You need to do some COM stuff), but Microsoft provides [an additional powershell module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) that exposes the commandlet `Get-WUInstall` that acts as a wrapper to make it a lot easier.

Comment: Powershell is the way of the future.